# How to select a column of data in excel?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I would like to calculate some numbers in an excel file.

Let say the excel file data looks like this:

```
Fruit     Cost
Apple     2
Orange    1
Grape     3
Mango     5
```

How can I calculate the mean of the cost?

At the beginning I open the excel file by:

```
with open("0001.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
```

Then I assign x equal to the selected column:

```
x = df["Cost"]
```

Then I calculate the mean of x:

```
Average=stat.mean(x)
```

Then print data:

```
 print(Average)
```

May I know what is wrong with this logic?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: I would suggest using pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Pandas** to read your excel/csv file.

This will create a `DataFrame` of your file-data. Then, for example, you can simply use `df[<column_name>].mean()` to get the average of that column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('0001.csv', encoding='utf-8')
print('Average cost: {}'.format(df['Cost'].mean()))
```

---

**Read more at**:

1. [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)
2. [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html?highlight=dataframe)
3. [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you so much.

May I know why it doesn't work if I write
with open("0001.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:

But it works if I use Pandas to read
df = pd.read_csv('0001.csv', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: @KKei As you wrote in your question, you try to open csv using `with open(...) as file`, then do `x = df['cost']`. Well, the reason this does not work is that your program does not know what `df` actually is in this scenario. Most commonly, `df` is used with `pandas.DataFrame`, therefore, `df['cost']` works with pandas as you are reading your csv using `df = pd.read_csv(...)`, which creates a `DataFrame` of your file data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the usage of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library for it.

You can do it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('0001.csv', encoding="utf-8")
print(df)

average = df['Cost'].mean()
print('Avg is:', average)

# output
df
    Fruit  Cost
0  Orange     2
1   Apple     1
2   Grape     3
3   Mango     5

Avg is: 2.75
```

Use the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for reading your csv file and [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for finding the average

Answer (score 0):

In dataframe their may be two type of column

1 without any special symbol then you can use.

```
1. dataframe.column (eg df.year)
2. dataframe['column] (eg df['year'])
```

2 contain special symbol

```
 1 dataframe['column'] eg(df['year-month-day'])
```